# gRPC metadata read from the server response are wrongly formatted

Tags: java, php, grpc

I have a Java application running on Spring and defining multiple gRPC endpoints. These endpoints are meant to be queried from multiple clients, one of which being in PHP, so I used the PHP lib for gRPC. Now I wonder how to properly get the metadata from the server in case of an invalid request, this metadata containing mostly constraint violations built by the Java validator and transformed into a collection of gRPC `FieldViolation` objects. In this example, the server is supposed to return one single field violation as metadata, with the key "violationKey" and the description "violationDescription":

```
try {
    // doStuff
} catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
    Metadata trailers = new Metadata();
    trailers.put(ProtoUtils.keyForProto(BadRequest.getDefaultInstance()), BadRequest
            .newBuilder()
            .addFieldViolations(FieldViolation
                .newBuilder()
                .setField("violationKey")
                .setDescription("violationDescription")
                .build()
            )
            .build()
        );

    responseObserver.onError(Status.INVALID_ARGUMENT.asRuntimeException(trailers));
}
```

On the PHP side, this is the implementation to retrieve the metadata:

```
class Client extends \Grpc\BaseStub
{
    public function callService()
    {
        $call = $this->_simpleRequest(
            'MyService/MyAction',
            $argument,
            ['MyActionResponse', 'decode'],
            $metadata, $options
        );

        list($response, $status) = $call->wait();
        var_dump($status->metadata);    // A
        var_dump($call->getMetadata()); // B
    }
}
```

**Result:** "A" outputs an empty array, "B" outputs the proper metadata, formatted as follows:

```
array(1) {
  ["google.rpc.badrequest-bin"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(75) "
I
testALicense plate number is not in a valid format for country code FR"
  }
}
```

Why is the metadata in the status empty, and why is the metadata retrieved by `$call->getMetadata()` is formatted that way ("I" followed by the violation key, then "A" and finally the violation description) ? How can I avoid to make potentially tedious transformation of this metadata client-side?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please log an issue on our grpc/grpc Github repo so that we can better follow up there? Thanks.